# Why is Blackbeard in Impel Down?

Tags: one-piece

I am currently watching *One Piece* and I'm at the part where Luffy is trying to escape Impel Down. Blackbeard appears at the entrance to Impel Down when Luffy and Co. starts the escape from Level 6.

I didn't understood what Blackbeard is looking for at Impel Down. In the first place, I thought he wanted to fight Magellan but after been poisoned, I think his goal wasn't this.

What is Blackbeard's purpose?

Comment: he wanted some new crew from level 6

Comment: Have you considered watching and finding out on your own? We could obviously tell you exactly what happens but that wouldn't but too much fun :/

Comment: @solalito I watched it but I didn't found out... I'm at episode 450. You could tell me what appens, even if I approximately know what will happen. One thing is shure, Luffy won't die ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you really want to know, you can watch the arc to the end since everything will be "explained" there, or you can read the spoiler.

If you really want to know ahead, [Darjeeling's comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/43570/why-is-blackbeard-in-impel-down#comment58411_43570) told you what happened:

> The whole reason Blackbeard took the title (Shichibukai) is so he can gain access to Impel Down and recruit some new members. He descended to the last level (6) where the most dangerous criminals are held (for the info, even the existence of this level is unknown to the general public) and recruited the members there. However, he made a competition. He told the prisoners to kill each other in their cells and he will rescue the winners (take them into his crew). At the end, there were 4 prisoners left: Vasco Shot, Avalo Pizarro, Sanjuan Wolf and Catarina Devon. Alongside them, another person joined the crew,  the former chief guard of Impel Down, Shiryu (Shiliew). 
> (From [Wikia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Blackbeard_Pirates))

Anyway, I recommend you watch the anime/read the manga and find out this on your own.

Comment: I will watch it and after I will accept the response ;)

Comment: I watched the episode where Shiryu gave Blackbeard and his crewmates the antidote against Magellans' poison. After this, Blackbeard said "welcome to the crew". So it is obvious he was looking for new crewmates. Thanks again for your complet response ;)